# copying binary files - source and target in c programming

Tags: c, file, binary, argv, argc

hello guys i made a program which copying binary files, but i have a problem: when im trying to copy the field of the source file to the target file its removing all the field of the target file. how can i solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int  main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FILE  *source, *target;
    const size_t buffer_size = 8192;
    char buffer[100];
    int strint[100];
    int  a;

    source = fopen(argv[1], "rb");


    if (source != NULL)
    {
        return  -1;
    }

    target = fopen(argv[2], "w+b");

    while (1)
    {
        a = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), buffer_size, source);

        if (!feof(source))
        {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), buffer_size, target);
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }

    }

    fclose(target);
    fclose(source);
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "when im trying to copy the field of the source file to the target file its removing all the field of the target file." What do you mean?

Comment: its just removing the field of the file and now its empty

Comment: Wrong buffer size, no check on `target`  Wrong use  of `feof()`, wrong size on `fwrite()`.

Comment: so can you please show me what to do to solve that?

Comment: Does the target file exist before you run the program? If so, do you want it to have the source file APPENDED to it or do you want it to be OVERWRITTEN by the source file? This "removing the field" language you keep using makes no sense.

Comment: @CareyGregory Overwrite

Comment: Then the program is doing what you want (mostly). Use the code posted by stackptr and it will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. You declare `buffer_size` to be 8192, but you only allocate 100 chars instead of `buffer_size`. So change the declaration. Also, constants are typically all-caps.
2. You need to write `a` bytes onto the destination file, not `buffer_size`, because the file may not even be `buffer_size` characters!
3. Check the return value of `fopen`; it returns `NULL` on failure. Check out `strerror` to print an error reason.
4. Your loop is wrong. Simply loop while `fread` returns BUFSIZE (that is, `fread` reads BUFSIZE characters).
5. Never use `system`, because it is highly unportable.

The revised program is

```
FILE *Fopen(const char *filename, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp;

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) == NULL) {
        strerror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fp;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const size_t BUFSIZE = 8192;

    FILE *src, *dest;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    size_t n;

    src = Fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    dest = Fopen(argv[2], "w+b");

    while ((n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)
        fwrite(buf, 1, n, dest);

    fclose(src);
    fclose(dest);
    return 0;
}
```

I have not tested the code, so tell me if something is wrong.

Comment: its removing the field of the target

Comment: @DanielZingerman You keep saying it's removing "the field." What do you mean by that? That's completely non-standard terminology nobody understands.

Comment: i means that there is a binary value in the file , and when im trying to copy its removing the value and the file becoming empty.

Comment: The source or destination file? Be more detailed @DanielZingerman Your statements are vague

Comment: @stackptr the destination file becoming empty

Comment: @DanielZingerman After you run this program, the destination file will contain **exactly** what the source file contained. If the destination file is empty that's because the source file was empty.

Comment: @CareyGregory the source file wasnt empty

Comment: Seems you actually wanted a ` while ((n = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, src)) > 0)`, no?

Comment: @Till Good catch. I hope the OP is paying attention because if the source file is smaller than that max buffer size constant it would cause exactly the symptoms he's seeing. The target file would be truncated to empty and nothing would be written to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
const size_t buffer_size = 8192;
char buffer[100]; // 100 should be buffer_size instead
```

You're not allocating your buffer size for buffer

Also, you're potentially writing the wrong number of bytes:

```
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), buffer_size, target);
```

you should be writing `a` bytes back so swap out `buffer_size` with `a`

Comment: what do you mean what do I mean?

Answer (score 0):

Among other issues noted, If by "its removing all the field of the target file" you mean the file target file has all contents removed *and you don't want that*, you need to read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), because it says:

> **w+**
>
> Open for reading and writing. The file is created if it does not
>   exist, otherwise it is truncated. The stream is positioned at the
>   beginning of the file.

Thus,

```
target = fopen(argv[2], "w+b");
```

removes all pre-existing data from the target file when you open it.

> how can i solve this problem?

Open the file in append mode:

> **a**
>
> Open for appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
>                 created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned at the
>                 end of the file.

like this:

```
target = fopen(argv[2], "ab");
```

Only use

```
target = fopen(argv[2], "a+b");
```

if you also want to read from `target`.